# converting double arraylist to 2 dimensional arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, arraylist

suppose I have an arraylist of the form `ArrayList<ArrayList<E>>` ... what would be the most elegant way to convert this into 2 dimensional arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes you don't have any nulls or anything tricky like that.
This also doesn't make any guarantees about the uniformity of the array (i.e. being "rectangular")

```
final int listSize = list.size();
E[][] darr = new E[listSize][];
for(int i = 0; i < listSize; i++) {
    ArrayList<E> sublist = list.get(i);
    final int sublistSize = sublist.size();
    darr[i] = new E[sublistSize];
    for(int j = 0; j < sublistSize; j++) {
        darr[i][j] = sublist.get(j);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes ... but your code will be more efficient (and IMO more readable) if you cache the `size` values in `final` variables.

Comment: glowcoder,highly appreciated if you could post a complete example

Answer (score 0):

If `E` is a generic class, we have the problem that one can't create generic arrays without reflection, and with Reflection we need the class object (or an example array object).

I'm not sure this is "elegant", but let's try:

import java.lang.reflect.Array;

```
<E> public static E[][] toArray(List<List<E>> list, Class<E> elementType) {
    E[] sample = (E[])Array.newInstance(elementType, 0);
    List<E[]> tempList = new ArrayList<E[]>(list.size());
    for(List<E> subList : list) {
       tempList.add( subList.toArray(sample));
    }
    E[][] finalSample = (E[][])Array.newInstance(sample.getClass(), 0)
    return tempList.toArray(finalSample);
}
```

This may need some `@SuppressWarning("unchecked")` for the casts from Array.newInstance.